# When did the distinction between "then" and "than" come about?

Tags: etymology, history

I'm reading A World in the Moone, by John Wilkins, 1638. I found the line: "I grant that some Astronomicall [sic] appearances may possibly be solved otherwise then [sic] here they are."

I knew what he meant by it (or at least I think I do), but I would have chosen "than" rather than "then." When did a distinction become prominent?

Comment: In 1638, English syntax (and spelling) were just being invented. One did as one thought best, or perhaps as one's printer thought best.

Comment: It's an interesting question. Have you checked the OED or another source to see when "than" was first used? Have you found any information that might indicate a possible direction for further research? If so, sharing it would be an appropriate way to stimulate discussion on this site.

Comment: Yes, Beliod, but that's more likely a typographical error than a deliberate choice.

Please remember that not just in 1638 but right up until about 40 years ago, typesetters had to work with characters read backwards. Try doing that at a productive pace and see whether it's hard to confuse "a" and "e"…

A very slight variation of the same problem gave us the expression "mind your Ps and Qs".